# Use SharpDX compiled from source?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, sharpdx, targets

I want to make use of the SharpDX library, a must-have is that I can compile the sourcecode myself.
I can compile the latest source code from their GitHub with ease using the Net40 configuration.
Now I would like to use the compiled project in my own project, I had found the following to do so:
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/379

This resulted in me doing the following steps:

- Download and extract the SharpDX sourcecode to "./SharpDX"
- Open the file "./SharpDX/SharpDX.sln"
- Build the SharpDX source code with configuration Net40 in the configuration manager
- Create file "./MyProject/Common.targets" with the following content:

  ```
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- set the location of SharpDX source code -->
      <SharpDXLocation Condition="'$(SharpDXLocation)' == ''">..\SharpDX</SharpDXLocation>
      <!-- the new property to include references automatically (as it was in old SharpDX.targets) -->
      <SharpDXIncludeReferences>true</SharpDXIncludeReferences>
      <!-- (optional) override DirectX version -->
      <SharpDXDirectXVersion>DirectX11</SharpDXDirectXVersion>
      <!-- disable usage of signed assemblies, as you won't have the needed private key to build them -->
      <SharpDXNoSigned>true</SharpDXNoSigned>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <Import Project="$(SharpDXLocation)\Build\SharpDX.targets" />
      <Import Project="$(SharpDXLocation)\Build\SharpDX.Toolkit.targets" />
  </Project>
  ```
- Create file "./MyProject/SharpDXHelper.csproj" with the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="BuildTarget">
      <Import Project="Common.targets" />
      <Target Name="BuildTarget">
          <Message Text="Building command for SharpDXHelper" Importance="high" />
      </Target>
      <Target Name="Rebuild">
          <Message Text="Rebuilding command for SharpDXHelper" Importance="high" />
      </Target>
      <Target Name="Clean">
          <Message Text="Cleaning command for SharpDXHelper" Importance="high" />
      </Target>
  </Project>
  ```
- Open the file "./MyProject/SharpDXHelper.csproj" with Visual Studio.

If I expand the "References" part of the "./MyProject/SharpDXHelper.csproj" I see all the required references with a warning icon, the warnings are like the following:

> Warning   13  The referenced component 'SharpDX' could not be found.  SharpDXHelper

I don't understand what I have done wrong, why does it not find the correct components?
I realize the "Toolkit" part is gone, and I expect those to fail loading, but I don't expect the others to fail.

To my understanding, I should be able to use the SharpDX library without issues if I add the "SharpDXHelper.csproj" as a dependency to any other project, am I correct on this one?

An image of the resulting problem can be found here:
http://puu.sh/dfmP4/c6ac1165ed.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To my understanding, I should be able to use the SharpDX library without issues if I add the "SharpDXHelper.csproj" as a dependency to any other project, am I correct on this one?

Not really.

A referenced project is not evaluated as an imported project (using Import task).

- **Referencing a Project B1 from a Project A1**: the project B1 is considered as a separable and compilable project. All the properties and targets defined by B1 are not visible in A1.
- **Importing a project B1 into A1** is like inlining the project B1 into A1. All properties and targets defined in B1 are visible in A1 (and overriding everything that is defined before the inclusion point)

This is a reason why we use ".targets" extension for imported projects to differentiate them from referenced projects.

Though It may be possible to develop such a referenced Project B1 that would be able to be "copied local" by A1 when compiling A1, but this would require to dig into how .NET/C# referenced projects are getting cross-compiled in order to do this. This is feasible, but quite a challenge to develop.

I recommend you to stick with the Import solution.

Comment: I took your advice and added    <Import Project="Common.targets" />    to an existing project file and, against my expectations, it actually worked. Without the Toolkit API of course, which should probably be updated sometime. Admittedly the project file that I added the import to was designed to work with NuGet (which I took out), so that might help the cause. When I wake up again I am going to see _why_ it worked with that project file and not with the one I made.